# Why does my console output change after declaring a json object?

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I have a class definition as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;
using namespace std;

class Test{

    public:
        Test *arrPtr[2];
        double data = 0.0;
        char label = ' ';
        char _op = ' ';

    Test(){
        this->arrPtr[0] = 0;
        this->arrPtr[1] = 0;
    };

    Test(double in, char l){
        this->data = in;
        this->label = l;
        this->arrPtr[0] = 0;
        this->arrPtr[1] = 0;
    };    

    Test(double in, Test* obj, char op){
        this->data = in;
        this->_op = op;
        this->arrPtr[0] = &(obj[0]);
        this->arrPtr[1] = &(obj[1]);
    };

    Test operator + (Test other){
        Test arr[] = {*this, other}; // arr contains calling object(this) and passed in other
        Test out(data + other.data, arr, '+'); // arr gets passed as pointer

    return out;
    }
};
```

which I am using like this:

```
int main(){

    Test a(100.0, 'a'); 
    Test b(100.0, 'b');
    Test c; c.label = 'c'; 

    c = a + b;

    Test arr[] = { a, b, c };

    for (Test obj : arr){

        if(*(obj.arrPtr))
            cout << obj.arrPtr[0]->label;

        json j;
    };
};
```

When the 'json j' line is removed the correct character is printed to the terminal. If the 'json j' line is included then the wrong characters are spit out in the termainl. Anyone have an idea why?

I haven't tried anything, this is such an odd bug I don't know where to start. My first guess is the issue has something to do with encoding.

Comment: Your code invokes *undefined behavior*. For sure your `operator+` is broken, as it leads to storing dangling pointers in `c`. Maybe also some other things, there's too many weird pointer shenanigans going on in this code

Comment: @UnholySheep can you elaborate?

Comment: `Test out(data + other.data, arr, '+');` - you pass a pointer to an array that goes out of scope after `return out;` leading to `out` having stored pointers to something that no longer exists

Comment: thank you! how else can I pass those two pointers contained in `arr` to `out`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.